# Question about TikZ arrows (sizes) used to label/point to equations

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, arrows, tikz-arrows

I am trying to use arrows to label a set of equations. This is what I have so far.

```
 \usepackage{tikz} % needed for arrows explaining equations
 \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning}
 \tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
 \everymath{\displaystyle}
 %% the above lines go into the preamble
 \tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]
 \begin{align*}
 \begin{array}{cll}
           & \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base](eq1){}} \delta\lambda = -\dot{\varphi}\epsilon & +\epsilon\tfrac{\partial}{\partial p}S = \epsilon(\dot{\varphi}-p)\\
 \text{Text1}\tikz[na]\node[coordinate](eom1){};   &  &\\ 
             & \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base](eq2){}} \delta p = i\epsilon(x\dot{\lambda} + (1-x)2i\dot{\pi}) & -\epsilon\tfrac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}S = \epsilon\dot{\pi}\\
         & &   \\
           &                                        & +\tfrac{i}{2}\epsilon\tfrac{\partial}{\partial \pi}S = -\tfrac{i}{2}\epsilon\dot{\lambda}\\
  \text{Text2}\tikz[na]\node[coordinate](eom2){};  &                                     &\\ 
            &\tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base](eq3){}} \delta\pi = -\tfrac{i}{2}(-\dot{\varphi}\epsilon) & -\tfrac{i}{2}\epsilon\tfrac{\partial}{\partial p}S = -\tfrac{i}{2}(\dot{\varphi}-p)\epsilon
 \end{array}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
     \path[->]<1-> (eom1) edge [right] (eq1);
     \path[->]<1-> (eom1) edge [right] (eq2);
     \path[->]<1-> (eom2) edge [right] (eq2);
     \path[->]<1-> (eom2) edge [right] (eq3);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{align*}
```

But this produces arrows that are not all of equal size.[image]

I would appreciate any suggestions to fix this.

Is there a way to remove the arrowhead (i.e. just have a line segment)? Also, is there a way to ensure that the arrows begin at a point on the centerline of the text?

Comment: a) Why do you think they are not equal? b) To have a line do `\path` without `->`.

Comment: (a) They are not equal because the distance between the beginning and end points is not the same :) I can understand that the arrow starting at "Text 2" and going up has to be longer because of the whitespaces inserted between the two sets of equations. I just put them in an array for convenience but maybe the better option is to put "Text2" in a floating position determined by the aesthetics of the arrows? My question was how to fix it. Also, the arrows emanating from "Text1" ought to be of the same length but they don't seem so.
(b) Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the following: `\tikzmark` which will let you set a point (where the arrow should point to), the tikz library `calc` (to calculate the mid-y-position between the two tikzmarks) and TikZ's `overlay` function.

Comment: arrow heads are the same (they are depend on line width, not on length!), length of lines are different, of course.

Comment: @Zarko, yes I'm referring to the length of the lines (not the arrow) heads. TeXnician, thanks for your reply! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see Texnician and I had the same idea, more or less.  I actually went to tikzmark and back again trying to center the lines.  Adding `\strut` was the key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc}
 \tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
 \everymath{\displaystyle}
 %% the above lines go into the preamble
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
 \def\arraystretch{2}%
 \begin{array}{ll}
    \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base](eq1){\strut}} \delta\lambda = -\dot{\varphi}\epsilon & +\epsilon\tfrac{\partial}{\partial p}S = \epsilon(\dot{\varphi}-p)\\
    \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base](eq2){\strut}} \delta p = i\epsilon(x\dot{\lambda} + (1-x)2i\dot{\pi}) & -\epsilon\tfrac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}S = \epsilon\dot{\pi}\\
                                            & +\tfrac{i}{2}\epsilon\tfrac{\partial}{\partial \pi}S = -\tfrac{i}{2}\epsilon\dot{\lambda}\\
    \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base](eq3){\strut}} \delta\pi = -\tfrac{i}{2}(-\dot{\varphi}\epsilon) & -\tfrac{i}{2}\epsilon\tfrac{\partial}{\partial p}S = -\tfrac{i}{2}(\dot{\varphi}-p)\epsilon
 \end{array}
\end{equation*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
     \path (eq1) -- (eq2) coordinate[midway] (m1);
     \node[right] (eom1) at  (m1 -| current page text area.west) {Text1};
     \path (eq2) -- (eq3) coordinate[midway] (m2);
     \node[right] (eom2) at  (m2 -| current page text area.west) {Text2};
     \draw (eom1.east) -- (eq1);
     \draw (eom1.east) -- (eq2);
     \draw (eom2.east) -- (eq2);
     \draw (eom2.east) -- (eq3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: demo]